# Why might the Terminal app not come to command prompt in a fresh installation of Chromeos on new Chromebook?

Tags: chromebook

[image]Just bought a new Asus Chromebook and did the initial setup.  Since I'm familiar with Debian-family Linux, I also “turned-on” the Linux environment,

I thought I was good to go. I wanted to do some command line stuff, so I fired up the Terminal app expecting it to get to a command prompt. But, it doesn't.  Instead,
it's got 4 topics that it wants be to deal with as though I hadn't completed some part of my installation. It wants me to ”manage Linux”, do something about SSH, do something with terminal-settings, and developer settings.

So, after a few hours being in `mumble-mode`, I did a Power Wash, and this time, didn't turn on Linux environment this time.  Nope, same problem. The terminal app still wants me to do those setup topics.

I went into those 4 topic areas, but I don't feel I understand exactly what the “answers” might be.  e.g. what about SSH?

What am I misunderstanding? Don't those questions have “default” starter values that I can re-visit after I do some command level tasks (real work)?

Comment: You should add a screenshot of those problems.

Comment: Honestly, without screenshots this reads like gobbledygook. Better add them.

Comment: ok...just added screenshot of terminal app when I launch it.

Comment: Dub...I get it now.  Because 'Terminal' was a runnable app, I mistakenly rhought it could do simple cmd-line stuff, even tho the Linux environment wasn't ebabled.  Maybe if it had been prefaced with a one-liner saying something like "This program has no cmd-line functionality until you enable the Linux environment and you may do so here".  (Though, in hindsight, ihat shouldli have been obvious, )  I was mistaking it for :crosh", Thanks for listening.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by the OP and doesnt need another answer and it probably has no value to future users.

Comment: As OP, I agree with you, Rohit.  Feel free to close it.  Or, point me to the button where I can close it.